# Finding a function with a certain behavior

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, graphing-functions

I'm searching what are the keywords or the good links to expand my researches.

I would like to get the equation ( for programming purposes ) of more or less this curve:
 https://i.stack.imgur.com/uv8rQ.png

Where the key values are: 
1 for the "crossing point" in Y axis "before it goes infinite" 
300 for the "crossing point" in X axis "before it goes infinite"

I would like to be able to manage the "curve amplitude"

Thanks in advance for any help

Answer (score 0):

You're going to need a curve-fitting procedure and this is best done by computer.

EXCEL has simple best-fit graphing functions that would suffice for most purposes-what you'll need are points on the curve as the x and y coordinates.

In other words, the simple picture of the curve ain't gonna be good enough, you'll need actual coordinates. And I think this is true for any simple program you use,online or otherwise.

Another useful program for finding the best fitting equation can be found here:

https://www.easycalculation.com/statistics/trend-line.php

My advice to you is go back to the original plotting program and improve the "fineness" of the x and y grid coordinates. For example, instead of having the x axis in units of 100, make it in units of 10. You should be able to get coordinates then and use them to get the best fit equation.

Comment: Thanks for you answer.

But so far, I can't get to get what I want. I don't think I'm searching for a best fit formula.

The graph is more a hint than supposed to be precise. The 2 points are:
point 1:   y = 1            x = 0.0001
point 2:   y = 0.0001   x = 300

Maybe the closest thing of how I understand it could be a bezier curve, where a third point could determine the curvitude of the function.